# How to end a while loop if a condition is met

Tags: python

I'm trying to complete some Python code, but am running into some problems. Basically, I am trying to prompt a user to input a desired username and password, as well as favorite color (as a security question) to use in a GUI that will initialize after the info is entered. The username and password must meet certain requirements, which you will find within the print statements in the code. If requirements are not met, the user will continue to be prompted to enter the information until all requirements are met, via a while loop that will be broken when requirements are met. The issue I am having is, the loop will end and the GUI will launch anyway, regardless of requirements not being met. It also appears the valid_pass function is being completely ignored. I'm new to Python, so I'm not much knowledgeable.

```
def valid_user():
  if (8 <= len(user) <= 24):
    valid_user == True
    print("Username meets requirements!")
  else:
    valid_user == False
    print("Please make sure your username meets length requirements. Usernames must be in between 8 and 24 characters in length.")

def valid_pass():
  if (8 <= len(pw) <= 24):
    if pw.isdigit() == True:
      if pw.isalpha() == True:
        valid_pass() == True
        print("Password meets requirements!")
      else:
        valid_pass() == False
        print("Please make sure your password meets length requirements. Passwords must be in 8 and 24 characters in length and contain both letters and numbers.")


while (use_inp):
    user = input("Set a username.")
    pw = input("Now, select a password.")
    user_answer = input("Select a favorite color")
    valid_user()
    valid_pass()
    if valid_user() == False or valid_pass() == False:
      continue
    else:
      break
    break
```

Comment: I would suggest using functions which take parameters and return values.

Comment: Your functions don't return anything. When you write `valid_user() == False` you are testing against the return value of the function, which is `None` since you don't return a value. Also the `isalpha` and `isdigit` functions don't work the way you think — they only return true is the whole string is a digit or alpha. The string `abc123` returns False for both.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to your specifications, let me know how it works. Thanks!

```
def valid_user():
  while True:
    user = input("Set a username: ")
    if (8 <= len(user) <= 24):
      valid_user == True
      print("Username meets requirements!")
      break
    else:
      valid_user == False
      print("Please make sure your username meets length requirements. Usernames must be in between 8 and 24 characters in length.")

def valid_pass():
  while True:
    pw = input("Now, select a password: ")
    if (8 <= len(pw) <= 24):
      if any(char.isdigit() for char in pw) == True and any(char.isalpha() for char in pw) == True:
          print("Password meets requirements!")
          break
      else:
          print("Password must contain alpha numeric and digits and be at least 8 length.")
    else:
        print("Please make sure your password meets length requirements. Passwords must be in 8 and 24 characters in length and contain both letters and numbers.")


user_answer = None
while user_answer == None:
    valid_user()
    valid_pass()
    user_answer = input("Select a favorite color")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the functions are superfluous here.

```py
usn_input: str = ''
pw_input: str = ''
colour_input: str = ''

valid_input_flag: bool = False

while not valid_input_flag:
    valid_input_flag = True

    usn_input = input('Enter a username: ')
    pw_input = input('Enter a password: ')
    colour_input = input('Enter your favorite colour: ')

    if not (8 <= len(usn_input) <= 24):
        valid_input_flag = False
        print('Please make sure your username meets length requirements. Usernames must be in between 8 and 24 '
              'characters in length.')

    if not (8 <= len(pw_input) <= 24 and any(curr.isdigit() for curr in pw_input)
            and any(curr.isalpha() for curr in pw_input)):
        valid_input_flag = False
        print('Please make sure your password meets length requirements. Passwords must be in 8 and 24 characters in '
              'length and contain both letters and numbers.')

print(f'Valid inputs:\nUsername: {usn_input}\nPassword: {pw_input}\nColour: {colour_input}')
```

Notice that I get all 3 inputs **before** doing any validation. There are cases where it is better to validate a certain input before asking for the next one.